# processing XML document using Xquery in dotnet core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xquery

As for my assignment i have to use specifically `XQuery` for processing the XML document.

In `.net` we have `linq-xml`, but the requirement is to use Xquery.

I have found some of the library for `.net` like

- Saxonica
- XML Prime

More list can be found here, https://github.com/maxtoroq/dotnet-xml#xpath-xquery-and-xslt

But i did not find any documentation or example with this implementation?

Is there any example that is specific for `Xquery` in `.net core`?

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

I have the `XML` in the format below.

```
<bookstore>
  <book category="COOKING">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30</price>
    <author>
      <name>Giada De Laurentiis</name>
    </author>
  </book>
  <book category="CHILDREN">
    <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
    <author>
      <name>J K. Rowling</name>
    </author>
  </book>
  <book category="WEB">
    <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>49.99</price>
    <author>
      <name>James McGovern</name>
      <name>Per Bothner</name>
      <name>Kurt Cagle</name>
      <name>James Linn</name>
      <name>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</name>
    </author>
  </book>
  <book category="WEB">
    <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>39.95</price>
    <author>
      <name>Erik T. Ray</name>
    </author>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

Comment: I think the XPath 2 implementation https://github.com/StefH/XPath2.Net (respectively on NuGet https://www.nuget.org/packages/XPath2/) works with .NET framework and .NET core (as it is .NET standard compatible) but that will only allow you to use XPath 2 based selection, which is an important part of XQuery 1 but of course doesn't give you any way to create new nodes or any FLOWR expressions.

Comment: as seen in the example i found that is similar to like `linq-xml`, is there any other way to use the `FLOWR expressions`?

Comment: As I said, the library supports XPath 2 (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/) but not XQuery 1;  XPath 2 is a subset of XQuery 1 and that subset you can use with that library integrated well into other .NET XML APIs. As for XQuery 1 or nowadays XQuery 3 or even 3.1, I only know that Saxon depends on IKVM and that is not compatible with .NET Core and is not further developed, in the future (autumn 2020) Microsoft itself intends to merge .NET framework and .NET Core as .NET Core 5 with full Java integration of its own so then Saxon probably has an option to become compatible.

Comment: I'm afraid Saxon does not run on .NET Core because it relies on IKVM, which doesn't support that version of the platform. Whether we will be able to run on the new Microsoft platform due next year is an open question: we simply don't know enough at this stage.